# NOT within WHERE as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a syntax where logical `NOT` could be easily applied to sql query depending on the parameter.

```
SELECT columns,
FROM table
WHERE (NOT dependent on parameter) condition
```

Use case - one query instead of two, what eliminats potential errors in case of having two separate, but almost the same queries, differentiated just by `NOT` within `WHERE` clause.

Comment: can You use 'or' Condition?

Comment: Perhaps `WHERE (condition) = booleanparameter`.

Comment: `Use case - one query instead of two, what eliminats potential errors` - which is likely to kill performance of such query. If you're happy with that, then `where (parameter = 1 and condition) or (parameter = 0  and not condition)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Can I negate a condition in a where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135164/sql-can-i-negate-a-condition-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the comment on performance considerations.

Comment: See this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html - i think i'd write a view of the common parts of everything and then select from the view with the varying parts of WHERE clause.